# mongoimport command doesn't work

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to use command mongoimport.
my mongoshell doesn't autocomplete ( when i use tab key) when i use mongoim. Where it puts me on doubt does mongoimport is not available ?

snippet:

C:\data\db>mongo
MongoDB shell version v3.4.4
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.4
Server has startup warnings:
2017-09-16T18:55:26.051-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2017-09-16T18:55:26.051-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2017-09-16T18:55:26.051-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2017-09-16T18:55:26.051-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]

MongoDB Enterprise > mongo
Mongo(        MongoBridge(  MongoRunner(
MongoDB Enterprise > mongoimp

I found relevant question here in stackoverflow, quit from 'MongoDB Enterprise' can solve this, when i use this command exit(), this makes complete exit from shell.

On server starts, it gives me warning message 'Access control is not enabled for the database' is this could be the problem ?

Help is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

**mongoimport** works from the **command prompt**, not from **Mongo Shell**. So go back to your system command prompt and fire it there. For example:

```
C:\>mongoimport --db students --collection scores --file scores.json
```

Here MongoDB imports data from **scores.json** file into **scores** collection in **students** database of your running MongoDB instance. So you have to ensure following 3 things to make your **mongoimport** work.

1. You are inside *System command prompt, not inside Mongo Shell*.
2. Your *Mongo instance is running*.
3. Your Mongo server **bin** directory is in **PATH** environment variable.

Comment: Happy to help you, @Suresh. Can you accept the answer by clicking the tick button on top left corner side?

Answer (score 0):

If the json file is a json array, make sure you add the `jsonArray` at the end of your command.
Using RLD example, you would write it like:
`C:\>mongoimport --db students --collection scores --file scores.json --jsonArray`

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the default MongoDB installation.
We are supposed to install MongoDB database tools.

1. Download MongoDB Database Tools(.zip) from the official website by choosing the correct option
2. Extract them to "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\bin"
3. You are done.

These 2 websites will be helpful:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2hsB_e0mFA&ab_channel=SriwWorldofCoding

https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools?tck-docs_databasetools